# display specific thumbnails inside prettyPhoto viewer

Tags: viewer, prettyphoto

I did not find any solution to my problem, which is:
i try to display a specific thumbnails inside **prettyPhoto viewer** , so i have this code:

> a href="images/full01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[1]" >
>   img src="images/thumb01.jpg" /
>
> a href="images/full02.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[1]" >
>   img src="images/thumb02.jpg" style="display:none"/
>
> a href="images/full03.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[1]" >
>   img src="images/thumb03.jpg" style="display:none"/

now, when i click on the image (thumb01.jpg) the prettyPhoto viewer appear and display (full01.jpg) image, but the  thumbnails inside the prettyPhoto viewer showing (full02.jpg,full03.jpg).

i just wanna to show the (thumb02.jpg, thumb03.jpg) as thumbnails.

please help me, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at this solution:

http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/comment/11215#Comment_11215

which tells you how to use specific thumbnails.